# Axis Label Value Removal

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I have a problem (as seen in the screenshot below) where my chart in Visual C# looks great, but I'd like to remove the first and last axis interval label  on the X-Axis (specifically the "3750" and "98250" in my bar chart).

In other words, these two labels shouldn't be visible/show nothing.

Code:

```
private void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double numIter, PvMean, PvStDev = 0;
        int nMin, nMax, numBins = 0;

        //NOTE: n is # vehicles sold; numBins is # of bins
        numIter = double.Parse(txtNumIter.Text);
        numBins = int.Parse(txtNumBins.Text);
        PvMean = double.Parse(txtMean.Text);
        PvStDev = double.Parse(txtStDev.Text);
        nMin = int.Parse(txtMin.Text);
        nMax = int.Parse(txtMax.Text);


        //+- 3 st devs
        PvMin = ((-3) * PvStDev) + PvMean;
        PvMax = (3 * PvStDev) + PvMean;

        PtMin = nMin * PvMin;
        PtMax = nMax * PvMax;

        //Bin array
        int [] Bins = new int[numBins+1];

        Random nPv = new Random();

        double Pt, totalprofit = 0;
        int Pv, n = 0;

        int i = 0;

        for(i=0; i < numIter ; i++)
        {
            //Use these vars to be able to produce random numbers
            int PvMinRand = Convert.ToInt32(PvMin);
            int PvMaxRand = Convert.ToInt32(PvMax);

            n = nPv.Next(nMin, (nMax + 1));
            Pv = nPv.Next(PvMinRand, (PvMaxRand + 1));

            //Equation for random Pv and n to get Pt
            Pt = n * Pv;

            //Increments total profit;
            totalprofit += Pt;

            //Bin index from rand
            int index = 0;
            //Call GetBinIndex method
            index = GetBinIndex(PtMin, PtMax, numBins, Pt);
            //Incremenents bin count by 1
            Bins[index] += 1;

        }

        //Increment of chart
        double Increment, incrCount, binRange = 0;
        binRange = PtMax - PtMin;
        Increment = binRange / numBins;
        chtSim.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = Increment;


        //Graph bars for each bin loop
        int j = 1;
        for (j = 1; j < (numBins+1); j++)
        {
            //Increases incr label value for each iteration above Pt Min
            incrCount = Increment * j + PtMin;

            //Graph bar for each index
            chtSim.Series[0].Points.AddXY(incrCount, Bins[j]);

        }
```

[image]

Comment: Now,brother,you tell us,is it possible for us to determine which chart control it is ? Add the name of the chart control(i suspect it's a third [arty chart control),then ask for help.Also your post will get many downvotes fast because you didn't try to fix your problem,even if you did,you didn't mention it in the post

Comment: I'm asking you. I've been trying to solve my problem for an hour, I don't care about how many up or down votes I have. I'm just trying to get some help. If I knew how to do it, I wouldn't be asking.

Comment: I'm glad that u asked but if we don't know which control is it,if u don't show how how u bind it to data,how can we help mate ?

Comment: I'm a freshman in an entry level college coding class and trying to learn, so I'm sorry, but I'm not understanding what exactly you're asking. For binding the data from an array, I'll paste my code here below:

Comment: Nooo.Dont paste your code in comments,rather add it to your post...And i am asking,what is chart control ?? Is it thaird party or what ?? And what exactly do you want to remove ?

Comment: I added it to the post, I just want to remove on the chart, where it says on the x-axis, "3750" and "98250", those axis values are not needed.

Comment: Is it a third party chart control ?

Comment: What do you mean by 3rd party, I don't understand? The application I'm using is Visual Studio 2015 on my computer.

Comment: When you open toolbox,you see the chart control right ? So,was it there when you installed visual studio for the first time or did you download it from the web ?? Untill you answer my question,i'll post an answer that'll do the job for you..But if u don't find it useful,make sure to comment before downvoting

Comment: Everything I'm making is from scratch out of Visual Studio 2015, I'm not downloading anything.

Comment: Ohhhhh no it was there when I downloaded Visual Studio. The Chart Control came with the Visual Studio 2015 software I initially downloaded.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question apologies. And trust me I won't down vote you for helping lol

Comment: Hover over `chtSim`. It should tell you what the type is. This is what Matt is asking, as charts like this aren't native to C# or .Net.

Comment: @Tim , u mean ZACK is asking ?

Comment: @zackraiyan correct, lol

Comment: nvm mate....Anyway OP , checkout my answer,hope it helps :)

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `AxisLabel` individually for each `DataPoint`.

By doing so, the automatic labels get removed. So you can write.:

```
int ix = chtSim.Series[0].Points.AddXY(incrCount, Bins[j]);
chtSim.Series[0].Points[ix].AxisLabel = incrCount;
```

.. in your loop.

Now only those labels you have set yourself are shown.